# Looping through directories in PHP?

Tags: php, file, directory

I'm working on a script that replaces all files within a directory and the subdirectories with a single string to get rid of the generic error message our software displays.

I made it work pretty easily with all files in a single directory, but then we ran it in a folder with subdirectories and as you can probably guess, it threw a lot of errors. I completely forgot about the subdirectories.

So now I'm making a script that works with subdirectories, but I'm stumped.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$files = explode("\n", shell_exec('ls'));
$count = 0;

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (empty($file) || $file == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (is_dir($file))
    {
        echo "Copying to {$file}/{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}\n";
        copy($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $file . "/" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        exec("php {$file}/{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}");
        unlink($file . "/" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        continue;
    }
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fh, '<!-- Generated %T by %h (%s) -->');
    fclose($fh);
    echo "Rewrote {$file}\n";
    $count++;
}
echo "Finished. Rewrote {$count} files. Don't forget to delete {$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}.\n";

?>
```

It ends up outputting this:

```
[root@proxy1 orgytest]# php p.php
Rewrote blah
Rewrote dfas
Rewrote dfasfsdjkfjsa
Rewrote dfdsafdsaf
Rewrote dfsaf
Rewrote orgy
Rewrote query
Rewrote scsew
Copying to test/p.php
Rewrote blah
Rewrote dfas
Rewrote dfasfsdjkfjsa
Rewrote dfdsafdsaf
Rewrote dfsaf
Rewrote orgy
Rewrote p.php
Rewrote query
Rewrote scsew
Copying to test/test/p.php
PHP Warning:  copy(test/test/p.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/orgytest/test/p.php on line 15
Could not open input file: test/test/p.php
PHP Warning:  unlink(test/test/p.php): No such file or directory in /root/orgytest/test/p.php on line 17
Copying to test2/test/p.php
PHP Warning:  copy(test2/test/p.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/orgytest/test/p.php on line 15
Could not open input file: test2/test/p.php
PHP Warning:  unlink(test2/test/p.php): No such file or directory in /root/orgytest/test/p.php on line 17
Finished. Rewrote 9 files. Don't forget to delete test/p.php.
Copying to test2/p.php
<!-- Generated %T by %h (%s) -->Finished. Rewrote 8 files. Don't forget to delete p.php.
```

What's weird to me is that it's trying to do things like `test/test/p.php` rather than `test/p.php`. I assume it has something to do with the fact that it's running from a higher up directory when it reaches that point.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `sed` or other simpler linux utilities?

Comment: @tandu, honestly I don't know what `sed` is. No reason not to other than the fact I'm just a PHP programmer. So I went with PHP. Don't really know much else.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is probably not what you expect, and the reason for constructing a path like `test/test/p.php`. My guess is when you exec `php test/p.php` then that's the value php places into `SCRIPT_NAME`. You could use the [basename](http://www.php.net/basename)() function to get around that.

Also, you should be using [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/escapeshellarg)() when dynamically creating shell commands.

Alternatively...

```
$self = realpath(__FILE__);
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__));
foreach ($ritit as $splFileInfo) {
    $fileName = $splFileInfo->getRealPath();
    if ($fileName !== $self) {
        file_put_contents($fileName, '<!.....stuff');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still kicking my ass. Thanks for the code, but I'd like to write my own code for it. Getting the task completed is of course number 1 priority, but I'd also like to learn it myself. I'll be home in roughly 40 minutes at which point I'll post my new code following your basename() suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from LS returning the contents of the base directory, not necessarily the one that houses your script.  I honestly would avoid exec, and just try to abstract your copying into a function, use php filesystem functions, and turn it into a recursive algorithm instead of trying to exec ls processes.

Answer (score 0):

SPL's recursive iterator's are ideally suited for this, I'd use something like the following

```
<?php
// get scriptname from $argv[0]
$scriptname = basename(array_shift($argv));

// optional argument indicating path to run this script in (defaults to current path)
if (!empty($argv[0])) {  
    $workspace = $argv[0];  
}else {  
    $workspace = getcwd();  
}

// Recursively iterate over files in the specified workspace folder and all subfolders  
try {  
    $count = 0;  
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($workspace)) as $file) {  
        // ignore the folders, and this script if present   
        if ($file->isDir() || $file->getFilename() == $scriptname) continue;  
        // write the file  
        echo "Writing to $file\n";  
        file_put_contents($file, '<!-- Generated %T by %h (%s) -->');  
        $count++;  
    }  
    echo "Rewrote $count files";  
} catch (Exception $e) {  
    // oops, likely invalid path, or unreadable folder   
    echo "Problem reading $workspace";  
}  
?>
```

SPL Manual:

[RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)
[RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score -1):

Try with something like this:

[Codingforums](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=71882)

or try to search on google for "php recursive directory listing" or anything similar.

With readdir() function you will get files and subdirectories in specific directory. So the key point is to figure out if it's just a file or it is a subdirectory with is_dir() function. Also make sure you will use full path to files in subdirectories when you want to open and edit it. So like i said try to use google and find something useful.